# pyglet label not showing on screen on draw() with OpenAI gym render

Tags: pyglet, openai-gym

I'm using a wrapper of OpenAI gym to create a graphical representation of a problem. For that, I'm drawing a circle with the given wrapper and then try to add some text.

My issue is, that only the circle shows, but the text label does not appear. Any suggestions on how I can make the text visible would be highly appreciated. Below a minimal example, that show the problem:

```
import pyglet
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 400
table_radius = 200

viewer = rendering.Viewer(screen_width, screen_height + 20)
table = rendering.make_circle(radius=table_radius, filled=False)
table_trans = rendering.Transform()
table.add_attr(table_trans)
table_trans.set_translation(screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2)

viewer.add_geom(table)

text = 'This is a test but it is not visible'
label = pyglet.text.Label(text, font_size=36,
                          x=10, y=10, anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom',
                          color=(255, 123, 255, 255))
label.draw()

viewer.render(return_rgb_array=False)
input()
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to manually implement the render function and insert the label after the tranform.disable()

```
    ## Content of the render function
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.viewer.window.clear()
    self.viewer.window.switch_to()
    self.viewer.window.dispatch_events()
    self.viewer.transform.enable()
    for geom in self.viewer.geoms:
        geom.render()
    for geom in self.viewer.onetime_geoms:
        geom.render()
    self.viewer.transform.disable()
    # Text
    label = pyglet.text.Label(
        "Hello, world",
        font_name="Times New Roman",
        font_size=36,
        x=100,
        y=100,
        anchor_x="center",
        anchor_y="center",
        color=(255, 0, 0, 255),
    )
    label.draw()

    arr = None
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
import pyglet
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering

class DrawText:
    def __init__(self, label:pyglet.text.Label):
        self.label=label
    def render(self):
        self.label.draw()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 400
table_radius = 200

viewer = rendering.Viewer(screen_width, screen_height + 20)
table = rendering.make_circle(radius=table_radius, filled=False)
table_trans = rendering.Transform()
table.add_attr(table_trans)
table_trans.set_translation(screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2)

viewer.add_geom(table)

text = 'This is a test but it is not visible'
label = pyglet.text.Label(text, font_size=36,
                          x=10, y=10, anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom',
                          color=(255, 123, 255, 255))
label.draw()
viewer.add_geom(DrawText(label))
viewer.render(return_rgb_array=False)
input()
```